# What's wrong with this switch statement and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

So you can probably see what I'm trying to make. And I thought it was working fine too, but then I noticed it will just load the same 5 posts over and over again. So I tried manually adding a switch statement, but that just returns "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment " which I Googled and found out a tiny little bit about. It's probably from me editing the variable I'm using the switch on? But anyways, how can I do this better, or fix it?

```
    $("#loadmore").click(function(e){
         if ($(this).attr("varl") == "30"){
           alert("All posts loaded");
         }else{
        var createDiv = $("<div class='loading" + $(this).attr("varl") +"'></div>");
        createDiv.hide();
        $(createDiv).appendTo("#left").load("loadmore.php?last=" + $(this).attr("varl"));
        switch($("#loadmore").attr("varl")){
            case '5':
                $("#loadmore").attr("varl") = "10";
            break;
            case '10':
                $("#loadmore").attr("varl") = "15";
            break;
            case '15':
                $("#loadmore").attr("varl") = "20";
            break;
            case '20':
                $("#loadmore").attr("varl") = "25";
            break;
            case '25':
                $("#loadmore").attr("varl") = "30";
            break;
        }
        console.log($("#loadmore").attr("varl") + 5);
        $(createDiv).delay(500).slideDown(500);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: does $("#loadmore").attr("varl") = "10"; work? I honestly never seen it used like this

Comment: As a sidenote, there is no valid attribute with that name, suggesting that you have invalid markup and probably should be looking at data attributes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("#loadmore").attr("varl") = "10";
```

should be

```
$("#loadmore").attr("varl","10");
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I thought about this but not that much.

Comment: It fixed the whole code btw, thanks again :) - Will become "correct answer" in 10 minutes, when I can

Answer (score 4):

```
var $element = $("#loadmore"),
    value = parseInt($element.attr("varl"),10); // always use a radix

switch ( value ) {
    case 5:
    case 10:
    case 15:
    case 20:
    case 25:
        $element.attr("varl", value + 5); // here's the problem
        break;
}
```

Comment: Blazemonger already pointed out the problem, but this seems like a much better code, so I'll vote it up :)

Comment: +1 for DRYing the code.  It could be that if the only possible values are the ones in the switch cases that the switch statement isn't even needed.

Comment: It's possible you could even replace the `case/switch` with `if (value%5===0) { ... }`

Comment: Anyone got a small code for that? My brain is toast at the moment, so I can't really do anything (as you can see by my mistake). Anyone mind making a small snippet of that?

Comment: Well, you need to think about other values if you use that approach -- you factored out `value==30`, but can `value` equal 35? or zero? Both will pass `if (value%5===0)` but not your `case/switch`.